# Disable specific keyboard shortcuts of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I found this old thread which said that Google chrome does not allow you to override the default keyboard shortcuts which are provided by the browser

[How can one disable shortcuts of chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162700/how-can-one-disable-shortcuts-of-chrome)

Has this situation changed now? I find the default Alt+Left behavior pretty annoying because it interferes with my default keyboard shortcuts. I like to use Alt+Left and Alt+right to move to the beginning and end of line rather than change page.

How can I override the default keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: dn't even try) it's nearly impossible/ easier to develop your own browser then change as example ctrl+shift+c in this, i think, galvanized sht

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the browser extension [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck)

Create a Keyboard Shortcut using "alt+left" and set the Behavior to "Do nothing"

[image]

Comment: I 'm a vi user, for whom `ctrl-h` means go up.   In chrome it means show the history page.   I tried using `shortkeys` to disable chrome's `ctrl-h`, exactly as above, but the cursed history page keeps coming up.   Has anybody figured out a way to deal with this?

Comment: @LeoSimon following some of the pointers on this page helped me: https://github.com/mikecrittenden/shortkeys/wiki/FAQs-and-Troubleshooting#Can_I_use_Shortkeys_to_disable_a_core_Chrome_shortcut

Basically add the shortcut through the Shortkeys settings and also through the Chrome extension Keyboard Shortcuts. Remember to reload your tabs.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Andreas_Hacker, I added shortkeys and set both ctrl+h and ctrl-h to do nothing.      I *think* i did it correctly, but can't put a screenshot into a comment.     What I did looked exactly like your screenshot above, with alt+left replaced by both ctrl+h, and then ctrl-h.     Then exited chrome and opened up again, but history was still coming up.     Any further suggestions?

Comment: @LeoSimon "It works on my machine" is all I can give at the moment ;-) Could you open a new question, so I can add a step-by-step answer?

Comment: NOT working as of Chrome 68, Ubuntu 16.04. :-(
`ctrl+1,2,3` for picking browser tabs still has precedence (i.e. over matching confluence shortcuts for headlines level 1,2,3…)

Comment: @FrankNocke fyi, the confluence headline shortcut is `ctrl+alt+1`

Comment: This does nothing on Chrome 120.0.6099.234 for MacOS.