# Disable google chrome's Ctrl + H

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to disable chrome's default binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> using `shortkeys` as discussed in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823832/disable-specific-keyboard-shortcuts-of-google-chrome/823897?noredirect=1#comment1603228_823897).   For some reason, the fix proposed by @andreas_hacker isn't working for me.    As per the comments in that thread, I'm posting this as a new question, so that Andreas can provide a step by step answer.